# Unable to create a constant value of type 'Tasker.Models.TaskOwner'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to setup security in a way that only content owner can only see his/her content. In addition, Manager should be able to view all the reports. Following is the piece of code that has been giving me the following error.

Error: Unable to create a constant value of type 'Tasker.Models.TaskOwner'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Code:

```
 public ActionResult Index()   
 {
     var owner = db.TaskOwners
 .Include(x => x.DirectReports)
 .Where(x => x.UserId==(User.Identity.Name.ToLower())).First();

     IQueryable<Task> tasks;

     if (owner.DirectReports.Count > 0)
     {
         tasks = db.Tasks
             .Include(t => t.Category)
             .Include(t => t.Priority)
             .Include(t => t.Status)
             .Include(t => t.Owner)
             .Include(t => t.Parent)
             .Where(t => owner.DirectReports.Contains(t.Owner));
     }
     else
     {
         tasks = db.Tasks
             .Include(t => t.Category)
             .Include(t => t.Priority)
             .Include(t => t.Status)
             .Include(t => t.Owner)
             .Include(t => t.Parent)
             .Where(t => t.Owner == owner);
     }

     return View(tasks.ToList());
```

Any thoughts, suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Which line of code is generating the error?

Comment: The last line of the code:  return View(tasks.ToList());

Answer (score 0):

it's probably complaining that it doesn't understand User.Identity.Name.ToLower() when it is trying to generate the SQL.  Try this instead

```
string userId = User.Identity.Name.ToLower();
var owner = db.TaskOwners
  .Include(x => x.DirectReports)
  .Where(x => x.UserId == userId ).First();
```

Comment: hmm, maybe it doesn't like owner being in the Linq.  Try making an int ownerId = owner.Id, then changing your Where statements to .Where(t => owner.DirectReports.Any( d => d.OwnerId == t.OwnerId));, and .Where(t > t.OwnerId == ownerId);